# Error: Too many DML rows: 10001

Tags: apex, list, insert

I have a question here, every time I run my code I first delete everything that is in the object, and then inserted a new list, when I try to do this simultaneously with the error ERROR System.LimitException: Too many DML rows: 10001 Do you know if there is any way to control this?

```
List < Clientes_Representantes__c > clientesRepresentantesExistentes = [SELECT Id FROM Clientes_Representantes__c];
                    if(clientesRepresentantesExistentes.size() > 0){
                        delete clientesRepresentantesExistentes;
                    }

                    List < Clientes_Representantes__c > clientesRepresentantes = new List < Clientes_Representantes__c > ();
                    System.debug('cod_cliList.size();'+cod_cliList.size());
                    for (Integer i = 0; i < cod_cliList.size(); i++) {
                        Clientes_Representantes__c clienteRepresentante = new Clientes_Representantes__c();
                        clienteRepresentante.Chave_Import__c = cod_chimportList[i];
                        clienteRepresentante.Numero_Cliente__c = cod_cliList[i];
                        clienteRepresentante.Numero_Representante__c = cod_repList[i];
                        clientesRepresentantes.add(clienteRepresentante);
                       System.debug(clienteRepresentante);
                    }

                  //Duplication the records
                   Set<Clientes_Representantes__c> setCliRep = new Set<Clientes_Representantes__c>();
                    List<Clientes_Representantes__c> CliRepAInserir = new List<Clientes_Representantes__c>();
                    setCliRep.addAll(clientesRepresentantes);
                    CliRepAInserir.addAll(setCliRep);
                    System.debug('CliRepAInserir'+CliRepAInserir);

                    if(!isTest){
                        System.debug('clientesRepresentantes'+clientesRepresentantes);
                        //upsert clientesRepresentantes;
                        insert CliRepAInserir;
                    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [per-transaction](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm) limit. You'll need to break your code apart by using [Batchable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_database_batchable.htm), [Queueable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Queueable.htm#apex_class_System_Queueable) or some other technique to stay under the 10,000 DML rows per transaction limit. There's way to break this limit under normal conditions. A transaction includes all the code that runs from start to finish in a single request, so if you're deleting a lot of records, that can cause you to reach this limit.